# Populate GAE Datastore Key Value in WTForms

Tags: python, google-app-engine, wtforms

I'm using WTForms and GAE (python) Datastore.  I'm trying to pass the key value to the form for CRUD purposes, but it's sending the object, not the key as a string. Here's the html output line:

```
<td> <input id="ts_list-0-key" name="ts_list-0-key" type="hidden" value="&lt;bound method TransactionSchedule.key of &lt;main.TransactionSchedule object at 0x04F19070&gt;&gt;"> </td>
```

All other fields are populating correctly.

Other info:
I'm using FormField and FieldList together to repeat multiple subforms.  To populate the subforms I'm using append_entry():

```
for ts in tslist:
    form.ts_list.append_entry(ts)
```

Can't seem to find this info anywhere, but maybe I'm a bad Googler.

I've tried:

-Converting the key to a string in the template (jinja2), but can't seem to get that to work

-Creating a `__str__` and a `__unicode__` method in the db.Model class that returns the value as a string, but I think I read somewhere that's not even allowed :/

Any help would be great!

Let me know if you need to see more of the code, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies.

The issue did have to do with `db.key` vs `db.key()` as RocketDonkey suggested.

What I ended up doing was this:

```
        for ts in tslist:
            ts_key = str(ts.key())
            form.ts_list.append_entry(ts)
            form.ts_list[-1].key.data = ts_key
```

There's probably a better way, but it worked.  It may be possible to set the key as a default value of the field using `str(db.key())`

Answer (score 1):

Tough to say without seeing more of the code, but it looks like somewhere in your code you have something along the lines of `ts.key` (assuming that `ts` is an instance of `TransactionSchedule`). `key` is actually a method (not a property), so you would need to call it as `ts.key()` instead.

For example, here is a simple class that has one method - `my_print`. Notice how referencing it as a property (instead of calling it as a method) returns similar output to what you have above in the `value` attribute:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     def __init__(self, a):
...         self.a = a
...     def my_print(self):
...         print self.a
... 
>>> c = MyClass('hello')
>>> c.my_print
<bound method MyClass.my_print of <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f11c16791d0>>
>>> c.my_print()
hello
```

Answer (score 1):

ts.key for NDB or ts.key() for db
use the cheat sheet if you have a bad memory like me

[Link to cheat sheet](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/mobilebasic)

Comment: Ha +1 - I've never seen that cheat sheet before and just may have to bookmark it :)